# How do I vary colors on a non-grouping factor in R's lattice barcharts?

Tags: r, plot, lattice

I'm trying to plot data in a barchart using lattice graphics.  I'd like to sort the bars by one factor and group by another (i.e., position by the first factor and contrast within position by the second).  However, I'd like to color the bars by the first (i.e., position) factor.

In the following example, the plot is rendered with paired red and blue bars.  Instead, I'd like two adjacent red bars, two adjacent blue bars, and two adjacent green bars.

```
library(lattice)

data = runif( 6 )
facA = rep( c( "a", "b", "c" ), each = 2 )
facB = rep( c( "1", "2" ), 3 )
df = data.frame( "FactorA" = facA, "FactorB" = facB, "Data" = data )
df$FactorA = = as.factor( FactorA )
df$FactorB = = as.factor( FactorB )
test_colors = c( "red", "blue", "green" )
test_plot = barchart(FactorA ~ Data, groups = FactorB, data = df, 
                     horizontal = TRUE, col = test_colors, origin = 0 )
plot( test_plot )
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not perfect but I think it does the trick (if I understood correctly your question).

```
barchart( FactorB ~ Data | FactorA, data = df, groups=FactorA, 
          horizontal = TRUE, col = test_colors, origin = 0,  layout=c(1,3))
```

`Factor B ~ Data | FactorA` means it divides your data in panels corresponding to `FactorA` and inside each of these group, split according to `FactorB`. The color follows what have been defined as the `groups`.

[image]

Comment: plannapus is correct here.  You can't do exactly what you're asking,  because of the 'lattice' package's assumptions, which do not allow for overriding the group color assignments.  The only other way to do this is to move to the 'ggplot2' package (which is a little more flexible) or the 'grid' package (which is less automated but infinitely flexible).

Comment: Comments have limited space for complicated explanations.  The 'ggplot2' and 'lattice' packages are both wrappers for the 'grid' package, but they take different approaches.  The 'ggplot2' functions generally take the approach of applying logical layers on top of the data, whereas the 'lattice' functions generally have a set number of parameters that can be initiated at function call.  The 'barchart' function, in this case, has a set logic for colors that will ignore any other color instructions if a 'group' argument is set.  The 'ggplot' function allows function independent color assignment.

Comment: @Dinre sorry you still in generalities. for the layer feature , there is `latticeExtra` with `as.layer` function. For the second point, in general we customize the panel function of the lattice.(here panel.barchart). That's said..why not to propose a `ggplot2 `solution. I will be happy to see it.

Comment: I selected this as the best answer as my solution uses an elaborated version this approach.  Thanks!

Comment: Adding `stack=TRUE` argument gives way better result.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to do this with 'ggplot2', you would write it like so:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=FactorA, y=data, group=FactorB, fill=FactorA)) +
geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge") + 
coord_flip()
```

From there, it's just cosmetic tailoring to suit your tastes, including picking the colors for the fill.